# Custom voice commands

Tags: automation, voice-recognition, google-voice-actions, open-source

I'm looking for an open source way to specify custom voice commands that use the Google voice recognition backend. It has to be open source and work offline. (I already managed to get the Google app which is responsible to voice recognition to work offline, restricted by Xprivacy and AfWall+.)

What I need to do is relatively simple. For instance when I say "Turn on light 1" it has to send a simple HTTP request to ’http://192.168.1.5/light/1/on’, when I say "Temperature to 23 degrees in the living room" it should use the url ’http://192.168.1.5/livingroom/temperature/23’ instead etc.

I know there are closed-source apps that can do this (Tasker for instance), but I I'm way too paranoid to install something on my device that needs network/Internet access and is closed-source. So are there any open source apps that could do this?

Comment: Did you even read the question?

Comment: Sorry for the last comment. I lost in answering two different questions. I was suggesting you [pocketsphinx](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx). It is also available for [android](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/)